# Batch Moving Folders based on their content

Tags: batch-file, directory, move

How would one batch move folders to another location based on the type of content they have.

eg: I have 1000 folders, some containing .zip's some containing .jpg's some containing .txt etc.

So based on my criteria I would like to move all folders that contain .zip to another location.

The folder may contain other files there as well we want to move the Folder and all its contents to another location if it has a .zip amongst the files.

I have seen references to moving files from folders based on file type which is not what I want to do.

If a folder has a particular file type I want to batch move that folder and all its contents to another location.

Comment: What happens if the same folder contains a .zip, a .jpg and a .txt file?

Comment: Hey Ken G'day,

Move the folder anyways. so long as the folder contains what I'm looking for move it and all its contents to another location.

Answer (score -3):

You can loop over each folder from a specific directory, and if the folder contains the file, append folder name to list. Them, loop over the list and move folders to the desired directory.

```
import os 
import os, shutil

dst = 'bla/bla/bla'
src = 'hur/hur'
ext = '.zip'

dirs_to_get = []
for directory in os.listdir(src):
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            if ext in file:
                dirs_to_get.append(directory)
    
def copytree(src, dst):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)

for file in dirs_to_get:
     copytree(src, dst)
```

Comment: This is Python code. The OP is using Windows batch. Read the question and its tags before posting an answer. There's no mention of Python in the post or its title, and no Python tag.

Comment: Where does it say there's a restraint? @KenWhite

Comment: The `batch-file` tag says it's for Windows batch. Read the tag description, which says *MS-DOS batch*. Random language answers aren't acceptable here. Base the answer on the question and its tags. Where does it say "Answers in any language are acceptable"?

Comment: I don't use python sorry windows only (win11 to be specific)

Comment: Looks like this is a tough one?